# Asus zenbook UX32VD: which kind of ubuntu installation? CUDA capable?

Tags: installation, asus, cuda

I have an asus zenbook ux32vd-r3001v with win7 64bit. I think that my laptop has win7 installed in EFI mode, but I am not sure.
Could I use "Windows installer for Ubuntu Desktop" or do I need to install Ubuntu in EFI mode?
After the Ubuntu installation, will I be able to CUDA compute with ubuntu? 
My laptop has two graphic card.

Answer (score 3):

I reply to myself: I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit in dual-boot mode with win7. 
On Ubuntu my laptop is Cuda Capable, but it must be careful because this laptop has a Optimus Technology for switching two graphic card (a Intel integrated with motherboard and a Nvidia Geforce GT 620 M). Bumblebee fix it for use Geforce (just use the command "optirun" for run any program that will use Geforce). For compiling Cuda-code is necessary install Cuda Toolkit, but without install the Nvidia's drivers, because they will be in conflict with Bumblebee's drivers (you can download this toolkit from NVidia's website).
If somebody needs my help for this laptop contact me!!!
I'm sorry for my not so good english.

Comment: Did you installed in EFI mode?

Comment: I don't remember very well (few months have elapsed). I think so.
You could follow the guide at 
http://webent.altervista.org/2012/09/12/come-installare-ubuntu-linux-12-04-o-successivo-sullo-zenbook-ux32vd/
You have to remember that Bumblebee is necessary for using the Geforce.